# iOS, Cocos2d-iphone: Can any tell me what are these codes @""?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

```
static NSString *CCDrawNodeHWTransformVertexShaderSource =
    @"uniform highp mat4 u_MVP;\n"
    @"uniform highp vec4 u_TintColor;\n"
    @"void main(){\n"
    @"  gl_Position = u_MVP*cc_Position;\n"
    @"  cc_FragColor = clamp(u_TintColor*cc_Color, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
    @"  cc_FragTexCoord1 = cc_TexCoord1;\n"
    @"}\n";
```

I got some errors in using cocos2d-iphone and xcode 7 and found the above code.

The error message:

```
Objects/CCMetalShaders/CCShaders.air: No such file or directory
```

What are the @"" codes? seems like they are opengl es or some c language? Can anyone points me to a direction of what they are and how can I learn more about them? Thank you.

Comment: It's called OpenGL Shading Language

Comment: Are you talking about the at symbols `@` themselves, or the contents of the strings?

Comment: Just the Symbol and what they are in general and what is the CCShaders.air file?

Answer (score 0):

try to set your Deployment target above 6
[image: Deployment target]

It works for me, at least..)